# Can someone explain what the third expression in python's indexing syntax represents?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Good Primer for Python Slice Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation)

I first ran across it last night for reversing a string `"Hello"[::-1]` and I can't figure out how it actually works.

```
"Hello"[::-1] # returns "olleH"
[1,2,3,4,5][::-1] # returns [5,4,3,2,1]
"Hello"[1:5:1] # returns "ello"
"Hello"[1:5:2] # returns "el"
```

My searches for "third expression in python index" have come up empty. What is this expression and how does it work. Obviously ::-1 reverses the list but I can't figure out what the other, positive values represent.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the third optional argument is called `step` or `stride`.
It's default value is **1**.

```
>>> 'hello'[::] # here the value of stride is 1, means take a step of one between two indexes
'hello'   

>>> 'hello'[::2] #take a step of 2 so starting from h -->l --> o 
'hlo'

>>> 'abcdef'[::-1] #negative step actually means 'abcdef'[-1:-len('abcdef')-1:-1]
'fedcba'
```

Answer (score 0):

In the last example, these are the characters that matches the step = 2.

```
"Hello"[1:5:2] # returns "el"
  ^ ^
```

Comment: Ah, ok, I didn't know it was called "step". Makes sense now. Thanks!

Comment: "Hello" was really an unfortunate sample string to choose.